# How to convert All json values to String without iteration

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON in which all the values have to be changed to string. The values may be a number, boolean, undefined or null.

```
{
    "obj1": [{
        "n1": "n",
        "n2": 1,
        "n3": true
    },
    {
        "n1": "n",
        "n2": 1,
        "n3": null
    }]
}
```

The expected result is all the values should be formatted as a `string`.

**Example:**

```
{
    "obj1": [{
        "n1": "n",
        "n2": "1",
        "n3": "true"
    },
    {
        "n1": "n",
        "n2": "1",
        "n3": "null"
    }]
}
```

By iterating through the JSON object we can do this, but is there any simpler way to do this.

Comment: What do you mean with "without iteration"? Some iteration is needed, hidden or explicit

Comment: You say you have JSON, so we are talking about one big string, right?

Comment: I know behind it needs iteration but any simpler way which it works behind

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could take [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) with a replacer function  and check if the values is a number, then take a stringed value, or just the value.

```js
var object = { obj1: [{ n1: "n", n2: 1, n3: true }, { n1: "n", n2: 1, n3: null }] },
    json = JSON.stringify(object, (k, v) => v && typeof v === 'object' ? v : '' + v);

console.log(json);
console.log(JSON.parse(json));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with [Json.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method

for example:

```
var object = { obj1: [{ n1: "n", n2: 1, n3: true }, { n1: "n", n2: 1, n3: null }] };
```

and to see the result, use Json.stringify()

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(object, (key, value) => value ? value.toString() : value));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const obj = {
    "obj1": [{
        "n1": "n",
        "n2": 1,
        "n3": true
    }, {
        "n1": "n",
        "n2": 1,
        "n3": null
    }]
};
const text = JSON.stringify(obj)
const newObj = text.replace(/:([^"[{][0-9A-Za-z]*)([,\]\}]?)/g, ':\"$1\"$2')
console.log(newObj);
/*
{"obj1":[{"n1":"n","n2":"1","n3":"true"},{"n1":"n","n2":"1","n3":"null"}]}
*/

// Em, let's format it
console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(newObj), null, 2));
/*
{
  "obj1": [
    {
      "n1": "n",
      "n2": "1",
      "n3": "true"
    },
    {
      "n1": "n",
      "n2": "1",
      "n3": "null"
    }
  ]
}
*/
```